# Jenkins build unable to initiate cucumber TESTS and times out

Tags: jenkins, testing, build, cucumber

I'm new to Jenkins. My basic Jenkins configuration did work earlier from command line nicely but since I did report configuration the TESTS aren't initiating anymore from Jenkins. I installed 'Email Extension' and 'Email Extension Template' plugins that started to cause the problem (explained) below but I now have removed them but the problem persists.

I see the spinning wheel under the last line (below) and nothing happens.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running cucumber.CucumberRunner
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 8791
Only local connections are allowed.
```

After sometime (18-20mins) the build just times out with a 'Failed to instantiate class stepDefinitions.LoginSUT'.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running cucumber.CucumberRunner
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 8791
Only local connections are allowed.
[1556614819.067][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 8470
Only local connections are allowed.
[1556615421.440][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 10001
Only local connections are allowed.
[1556616023.903][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
7 Scenarios (7 failed)
28 Steps (7 failed, 21 skipped)
30m7.588s
```

Here is the snapshot from the Jenkins test results. It seems like something is blocking it but I have not been able to figure out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. 
[image]

My CucumberRunner.java class

```
//always run this as part of the cucumber class
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

// additional options for this cucumber class
@CucumberOptions(
        features = { // "src/test/resources/features/WebCorporateJourney.feature"//,
                "src/test/resources/features/WebRetailJourney.feature" }, 
        glue = { "stepDefinitions" },
        plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html" }, 
        monochrome = true)

// bridges between feature file and step definition and help them talk to each
public class CucumberRunner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
    }
}
```

**Edit-1:** Adding code as requested

My AbstractDriver.Java class

```
public class AbstractDriver {

    protected static WebDriver driver;

    protected WebDriver getDriver() {
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        // if driver hasn't instantiated then instantiate it
        if (driver == null) {
            // instantiates the driver
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            // driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        }
        // returns same instance of the driver
        return driver;
    }
}
```

My LoginSUT.java stepDefinition

```
public class LoginSUT extends AbstractDriver {

    WebDriver driver = getDriver();

    @Given("^user is on website$")
    public void user_is_on_website() throws Throwable {
        // passing admin credentials
        driver.get("http://admin:test@mySUTlink.com/");
    }

    @When("^user enters credentials$")
    public void when_user_enters_credentials() throws Throwable {
        // Maximising the Browser window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // Accepting Cookies
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Accept']")).click();

    }

    @Then("^user is logged on$")
    public void user_is_logged_on() throws Throwable {

        boolean isDisplayed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='my text to verify']")).isDisplayed();
        if (isDisplayed) {
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("USER VERIFICATION: User logged on successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("USER VERIFICATION: User failed to logon");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit-2:** The tests from Command line were working but through Jenkins were failing

Comment: Looks like it cannot start ChromeDriver. Can you add the code (including any relevant configuration) you are using to start ChromeDriver to your question? And if relevant the code for stepDefinitions.LoginSUT?

Comment: Thanks @Marit I have added the code. I hope that helps. My concern is it did work earlier and after configuring reports it stopped. Now that I have reverted changes it's not working...very peculiar.

Comment: could you try using an [@After hook](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#after) instead of @AfterClass? I'm not sure @AfterClass is supported

Comment: Hi @Marit, my problem has now been resolved. I'm running Jenkins as windows service. I had to enable 'Allow service to interact with desktop' option from the Jenkins service. Since then I have had no issues. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After looking around for solution. I found out that Jenkins was installed on my machine as Windows service and the Jenkins Logon properties to allow the interaction was disabled. So I,

open Services -> look for Jenkins -> right-click Properties -> under Log On tab 
tick the box **Allow service to interact with desktop**

This change initiated my cucumber tests and I was able to view my tests being run under 'Console Output'